# Xcode 4.2 debugger gdb in iOS is on showing every packet, how do I turn it off?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gdb, xcode4.2

When I debug an app on a device I get this:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Fri Sep 16 06:56:50 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-42389-80
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
Sending packet: $Hc-1#09...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $qC#b4...Ack
Packet received: QC0
Sending packet: $qStepPacketSupported#2b...Ack
Packet received: OK
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:#f7...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:5348454c4c3d2f62696e2f62617368#42...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:544d504449523d2f7661722f666f6c646572732f64372f626268363934673537317a307239396835375f39307a347230303030676e2f542f#82...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:4170706c655f5075625375625f536f636b65745f52656e6465723d2f746d702f6c61756e63682d46527963466d2f52656e646572#92...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:555345523d427279616e#71...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:434f4d4d414e445f4d4f44453d756e697832303033#39...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:5353485f415554485f534f434b3d2f746d702f6c61756e63682d396b533777522f4c697374656e657273#15...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:5f5f43465f555345525f544558545f454e434f44494e473d30783146353a303a30#82...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:504154483d2f446576656c6f7065722f7573722f62696e3a2f7573722f62696e3a2f62696e3a2f7573722f7362696e3a2f7362696e3a2f7362696e3a2f62696e3a2f7573722f7362696e3a2f7573722f62696e#b5...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:5057443d2f55736572732f45646974426179322f4c6962726172792f446576656c6f7065722f58636f64652f44657269766564446174612f694d61672d68616c6e6d77647178766765717165617161796f6179726e676f66732f4275696c642f50726f64756374732f44656275672d6970686f6e656f73#b6...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:53484c564c3d30#5e...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:484f4d453d2f55736572732f4564697442617932#26...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:4c4f474e414d453d427279616e#6a...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:444953504c41593d2f746d702f6c61756e63682d5364324234732f6f72672e783a30#1f...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:4c494e45533d3234#c8...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:434f4c554d4e533d3830#f7...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QEnvironmentHexEncoded:4e53556e6275666665726564494f3d594553#2f...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QSetDisableASLR:1#ce...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $A182,0,2f707269766174652f7661722f6d6f62696c652f4170706c69636174696f6e732f44333545464430422d463735312d344131432d393534432d3643383937414338463745362f694d616720322e332e6170702f694d616720322e33#ac...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $qLaunchSuccess#a5...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $qC#b4...Ack
Packet received: QC18bf
Sending packet: $qOffsets#4b...Ack
Packet received: 
Sending packet: $QStartNoAckMode#b0...Ack
Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $QSetMaxPayloadSize:3fb#3d...Packet received: OK
Sending packet: $?#3f...Packet received: T11metype:5;mecount:2;medata:10003;medata:11;thread:2a03;qaddr:3f166d80;pc:2fe01028;
Sending packet: $pf#d6...Packet received: 2810e02f
[Switching to process 10755 thread 0x2a03]
[Switching to process 10755 thread 0x2a03]
Sending packet: $qShlibInfoAddr#6a...Packet received: 2fe22c70
Sending packet: $qSymbol::#5b...Packet received: 
Packet qSymbol (symbol-lookup) is NOT supported
Sending packet: $m2fe22c40,40#25...Packet received: 00000000182ce22fc10ae22f01000000542ce22fb82be22fc50ae22f182ce22fc70ae22f00000000542ce22f000000000c00000000000000000000008810e02f
Sending packet: $m2fe22c80,40#29...Packet received: 000000000000e02f0000000081efe12f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000702ce22f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00000,40#ea...Packet received: cefaedfe0c00000009000000070000000b000000b40400008500000001000000480100005f5f54455854000000000000000000000000e02f0020020000000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00040,40#ee...Packet received: 00200200050000000500000004000000000000005f5f74657874000000000000000000005f5f54455854000000000000000000000010e02f14ca010000100000
Sending packet: $m2fe00080,40#f2...Packet received: 0c00000000000000000000000004008000000000000000005f5f63737472696e67000000000000005f5f544558540000000000000000000014dae12f5c3b0000
Sending packet: $m2fe000c0,40#1d...Packet received: 14da01000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000005f5f6763635f6578636570745f7461625f5f54455854000000000000000000007015e22f
Sending packet: $m2fe00100,40#eb...Packet received: e0060000701502000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5f636f6e73740000000000000000005f5f5445585400000000000000000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00140,40#ef...Packet received: 501ce22f08010000501c020004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000140200005f5f44415441000000000000000000000020e22f
Sending packet: $m2fe00180,40#f3...Packet received: 00a002000020020000100000030000000300000007000000000000005f5f6e6c5f73796d626f6c5f707472005f5f44415441000000000000000000000020e22f
Sending packet: $m2fe001c0,40#1e...Packet received: cc000000002002000200000000000000000000000600000000000000000000005f5f6d6f645f696e69745f66756e63005f5f4441544100000000000000000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00200,40#ec...Packet received: cc20e22f10000000cc2002000200000000000000000000000900000000000000000000005f5f64617461000000000000000000005f5f44415441000000000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00240,40#f0...Packet received: 00000000e020e22f24030000e02002000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5f636f6e73740000000000000000005f5f444154410000
Sending packet: $m2fe00280,40#f4...Packet received: 00000000000000001024e22f5c080000102402000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5f616c6c5f696d6167655f696e666f5f5f4441
Sending packet: $m2fe002c0,40#1f...Packet received: 544100000000000000000000702ce22f54000000702c02000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005f5f636f6d6d6f6e0000000000000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00300,40#ed...Packet received: 5f5f4441544100000000000000000000d02ce22f3c040000000000000400000000000000000000000100000000000000000000005f5f62737300000000000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00340,40#f1...Packet received: 000000005f5f44415441000000000000000000001031e22f6d860200000000000400000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000038000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00380,40#f5...Packet received: 5f5f4c494e4b4544495400000000000000c0e42f00f000000030020030e600000100000001000000000000000000000002000000180000006844020030040000
Sending packet: $m2fe003c0,40#20...Packet received: 74770200289a00000b00000050000000000000002a0400002a040000060000003004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00400,40#ee...Packet received: a8760200330000000000000000000000003002000d0200000f0000001c0000000c0000002f7573722f6c69622f64796c640000001b00000018000000be7c0b49
Sending packet: $m2fe00440,40#f2...Packet received: 1a943054ad12eb5060f1da0625000000100000000000050000000000050000005400000001000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Sending packet: $m2fe00480,40#f6...Packet received: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002810e02f0000000026000000100000006840020000040000
Sending packet: $m2fe004c0,40#21...Packet received: 1d00000010000000a011030090040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It continues, this is just some of it.  I want to know how to return to the default Xcode version of the debug window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my user directory, the file .gdbinit had the following:  `set debug remote 10`

Delete or rename the file solved this.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere something executed `set debug remote on` for you. To turn it off, do `set debug remote off`.

Comment: You type `set debug remote off` at the `(gdb)` prompt. If that helps, you can try to figure out where it is set to `on`, and remote that.

Comment: Do you know how to get Xcode to default to this, so I don't have to do it every time?

Comment: I tried this at the gdb prompt, it doesn't work, still shows the long list.